# Disable auto detection of phone numbers in Chrome

Tags: android, html, google-chrome

How do I stop Google Chrome on Android from auto detecting phone numbers in HTML pages and making them clickable?

Clicking the text in the following web page opens the dialer application:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html>
    <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
     <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    </head>

    <body style="color:red">
     04.07.2016
    </body>
    </html>
```

I'm looking for a solution in HTML.

Here's a test page: https://mediaguide.traumwelt.tv/index3.html

Comment: `<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />` these doesnt solve problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not @kuchar , Chrome just ignores it.

Comment: hmmm for me this text `04.07.2016` is not clickable in chrome on sony z3